# I want to remove the title in the top-left corner

Tags: acmart, remove

My document uses the following:

```
\documentclass[sigconf, nonacm]{acmart}
```

whereas `acmart.cls` is found in the following link:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KkcxPx1vrO1cLTkTREMBVb1CQKaxolHvO1MXqpv0MzM/edit?usp=sharing

But I want to remove the top-left corner's title in this image:

[image]

I wonder which line in acmart.cls is relevant to removing this title..
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [acmart – Class for typesetting publications of ACM](https://ctan.org/pkg/acmart?lang=en) from CTAN

The "title" command has an optional parameter, allowing the author to define a "short title" to be used in page headers.

Use `\title[]{I want to remove \\ This Title}` instead of  `\title{I want to remove \\ This Title}`